# Can multiple holidays display using table_calendar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I have upgraded `table_calendar` to the current latest version (`3.0.3`). Now it will change many methods. Now I need to add multiple holidays in the same. How can I do this? I tried this as the following method, but it will display only one day.

```
TableCalendar(
...

holidayPredicate: (day) => _getHolidays(day),

...
)
```

```
_getHolidays(day) {
    return day == DateTime.utc(2021, 12, 02);
}
```

I need to pass a list of holidays here. But this supports only one day. It gives an error as `The return type 'List<dynamic>' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context.` when I try to pass the list.

Are there any alternative methods on `table_calendar` or any suggestions to fix this issue? I cannot use `eventLoader`, because I already use it to mark some events in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should using your _getHolidays method to process other day list. It will return true/false whether the day is holiday or not.

Answer (score 0):

I create a list of holidays and use the *contains* method to return boolean.

[See the code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtUfO.png)

```
TableCalendar(
...

holidayPredicate: (day) =>  _getHolidays(day),

...
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74143185/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.